# Crafting S1AP packets using Scapy

Tags: scapy, sctp, lte, 4g

I am looking at a project that requires the crafting of S1 Application Protocol (S1AP) packets. It is used between a eNodeB and MME of a 4G LTE network. S1AP is IP based and carried by the Steam Control Transmission Protocol (SCTP).

Does anyone have any idea if the current library for SCTP in Scapy is sufficient to do this, or I might have to define a new protocol?

My first goal is to emulate a connection (via a program) to a physical MME, anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your development environment & requirement. In the case of linux/FreeBSD based development setup, the libsctp and ASN.1 tools should be enough for having S1-AP over SCTP protocol in the interface with the MME.

Coming to Scapy, note that it is based on python.

Scapy seems to have support for all types of SCTP chunks and so it must most probably be fine for your testing.

S1-AP protocol uses ASN.1. For generating S1-AP packets, you should integrate with ASN.1 for S1-AP encoding/decoding and use over scapy. Scapy provides support for ASN.1.

The S1-AP support extension should be done by you. The best part is that you can extend Scapy without having to edit source files for making your automated tool based on the type of requirement.